# VBA read CSV with delimiter in string

Tags: csv, vbscript, import

I'm trying to read a .csv to work with it in an .accdb

The file has ; as delimiter and "" as string qualifier.
Young and naive as I was I just split the file at the delimiter:

```
Set oFSO = New FileSystemObject
Set oStream = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sFilePath, ForReading)
Do Until oStream.AtEndOfStream
    sLine = oStream.ReadLine
        sArray = Split(sLine, ";")
        ....
```

Now I got a line that reads:

```
"String";"Str;ing";0;0;0;"String"
```

So I have delimiter inside one of the strings which makes the code above not work. Any ideas how to solve this?

EDIT:

I've found someone with a similar problem, only with a comma as delimiter. And they solved it using regular expressions.
The problem: I'm absolutely not good with regular expressions. In the example the used this expression and code:

```
Function regLine(sLine As String) As String
Dim oRegEx As RegExp
    Set oRegEx = New RegExp
    oRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    oRegEx.Global = True

    ' Pattern: ",(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*(?![^"]*"))"
    oRegEx.Pattern = ",(?=([^" & Chr(34) & "]*" & Chr(34) & "[^" & Chr(34) & "]*" & Chr(34) & ")*(?![^" & Chr(34) & "]*" & Chr(34) & "))"

    regLine = oRegEx.Replace(sLine, ";")
End Function
```

So I don't really understand the expression. My first idea was to replace the comma with a semicolon but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Option Explicit 

Dim line 
    line ="""String"";""Str;ing"";0;0;0;""String"""
    WScript.Echo line

Dim aFields
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "(""[^""]*"")?;"
        .Global = True 
        aFields = Split(.Replace(line, "$1"&Chr(0)),Chr(0))
    End With

Dim field
    For Each field In aFields
        WScript.Echo field
    Next
```

Code is `.vbs`, but shows how to use the regular expression to replace semicolons not enclosed in quotes with a null character and use the null character to split the line into its fields.

Comment: not sure if I did something wrong, but the for me the output string looks like    ;;0;0;0;"String"

Comment: @FNR, to test, copy code, save as `test.vbs`, run with `cscript test.vbs` to execute on console or double click on file. I've also tested it as VBA in excel, replacing `Wcript.Echo` with `MsgBox`, including the reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions` or using `CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")`  and in both cases it works. Please, include in your question the code you are using so we can see where it could fail.

Comment: `Set oRegEx = New RegExp
       oRegEx.Global = True
       oRegEx.Pattern = "(""[^""]*"")?;"
       sLine2 = oRegEx.Replace(sLine, ";")
       regLine = Split(sLine2, ";")`

sLine is the same string as in my original post

Comment: @FNR, **1** - the regular expression is using a capture group to separate the quoted strings from semicolons, you forgot the `$1` in the replace that should look as `.Replace(sLine, "$1;")` BUT **2** - I see no reason to replace a semicolon with a semicolon, you will end with the same problem. Use as replacement a character not present in data (as `Chr(0)`) and split using this character.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem now by writing a loop, that deletes the delimiter if it is in a string.

```
Function fixLine(sLine As String)
Dim i As Long
Dim bInString As Boolean

bInString = False
fixLine = ""
For i = 1 To Len(sLine)
    If Mid(sLine, i, 1) = Chr(34) Then
         If bInString Then
            bInString = False
        Else
            bInString = True
        End If
     End If
    If bInString And Mid(sLine, i, 1) = ";" Then
    Else
        fixLine = fixLine & Mid(sLine, i, 1)
    End If
Next
End Function
```

It kind of feels quick and dirty and I'm not sure about the performance but it works.

EDIT:
I also worked with theabove example I found. It replaces the delimiter in a line outside of strings. So I replaced the delimiter with Chr(0) which I know won't apear in a line and then split at the new delimiter.

```
Function regLine(sLine As String) As String()
Dim oRegEx As RegExp
Dim sLine2() As String
    Set oRegEx = New RegExp
    oRegEx.Global = True

    'Pattern: ";(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*(?![^"]*"))"
    oRegEx.Pattern = ";(?=([^" & Chr(34) & "]*" & Chr(34) & "[^" & Chr(34) & "]*" & Chr(34) & ")*(?![^" & Chr(34) & "]*" & Chr(34) & "))"

    sLine2 = oRegEx.Replace(sLine, Chr(0))
    regLine = Split(sLine2, Chr(0))
End Function
```

Comment: @MCND's answer proves that no dirty hacks are necessary.

Comment: Much better, but MCND's approach/pattern is still superior.

Answer (score 0):

My first question is: Is there any case where a ";" in the string values is a valid string?  If so, I don't see any way other than manually verifying the data.

If not, how large is the input file?  If it's not too big (for various definitions of "too" :-) ) then just manually scan it for errors.

If it is very large, I'd simple write a preprocesser program that reads the string values then deletes any ";" in those where it occurs.  Such a program is only about a dozen lines long.  Then run the clean file into Access.

Comment: Sadly it is a very big file, baout 40000 lines. So doing it manually is not really an option

Comment: @MCND's answer proves that neither pessimism nor manual modification is justified.